# Exception and Interrupt difference

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-architecture, interrupts, exceptions

I know a Exception is a software Interrupt however after a Interrupt the program counter always returns to the address before the Interrupt was thrown but after a Exception a program may be terminated if the Exception isnt handled properly which means that the program  counter not any longer points to a memory address of a instruction of the program, so why is the handling so much different?

Suppose we have a program which divides 2 numbers A from B.First the program asks for B ,prints B then asks for A ,prints A calculates B/A and in the end prints B/A.Lets ignore the interrupts from the keyboard for the time being.

So the program takes the first input as B then a display interrupt interrupts the main program and instructions to display B on the screen are executed then returns to the current instruction of the main program when the interrupt occured.Now lets assume that A is 0 and the main program doesnt have built in code which handles the exception(divide by 0).Now there is a big difference between the screen interrupt and the DivideByZero exception because in the case of the screen interrupt after instructions to display B on the screen are executed the instructions of the main program continue to be executed normally while in the case of the DivideByZero exception the program just stops and because the OS cannot handle the exception the program is exitted by the computer.

So in 1 case the instructions of the main program continue to be executed while in the other case no more instructions of the main program will be executed.

So why is the handling of different type of Interrupts so different?

Answer (score 1):

In either case the control for the exception or interrupt is handled by the operating system before code execution is handed back to the application.

The general flow would be

1. Program code executes
2. An interrupt is raised by the hardware
3. The operating system performs a [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) and runs the interrupt code. The current programs state is stored and saved
4. The interrupt code does the necessary work to handle the interrupt, storing data in buffers and so on
5. The interrupt returns control to the operating system.
6. The operating system performs another context switch, this time to the program that was interrupted and execution continues.

An exception can be thought of as a special kind of interrupt. If the program performed an operation necessitating it be stopped or killed then obviously there is nothing to pass control back to.

In that case the operating system will simply move on and perform a context switch to the next program that requires CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

From the hardware's perspective, an interrupt is a particular type of exception.

An exception occurs whenever normal program execution is suspended and an exception handler is run. Usually, the CPU enters a "more privileged" mode at the same time as the jump, and that is the only way to elevate privilege.

Exceptions can be *precise*, meaning that they occur on a particular instruction, and the handler code is informed which instruction that is. This is typically the case for exceptions that are caused by the currently running program, such as when an invalid instruction is decoded.

Whether particular program errors cause precise exceptions is defined by the implementation -- some architectures execute instructions sequentially, some architectures go to great lengths to pretend sequential execution and roll back speculatively executed code if a memory access turns out to be illegal, and some leave it to software to investigate the error.

Interrupts are typically imprecise exceptions because there is no relationship between the interrupt being raised and the code being executed.